# Escape reserved words for MS-SQL, Oracle and PostgreSQL databases with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table column which name is 'KEY' and its defined as follows;

```
   @Column(name="KEY", nullable = false)
   private String key;
```

This works on oracle and postgresql but in Mssql its getting error because of being reserved word,I have tried `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` property but it causes another exception for me which is DuplicateMappingException for the other entities. I don't want to make change on DB side, I already tried to make manuel escape like backstick, `\"KEY\"` and `[KEY]` but didnt work for all of them. How to escape reserved words for this databases?


Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh, weird. Both double quotes and backticks should do the trick. What exception are you getting?

Comment: backsticks works well for mssql and postgresql but in oracle i got Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PERMISSION0_"."key": invalid identifier.. for double quotes i got same error in ms sql.

Comment: I don't know if this is still the case, but last I went through the code, the parser explicitly detected and converted mysql identifier quotes to your local dialect quotes. Try `name="\`KEY\`"`

Comment: Its not work for oracle, i want to escape that column for all databases i specified at title

Comment: From what I gather, `"` is supported as a way of quoting identifiers for SQL Server. In Oracle, quoting makes the identifier case-sensitive, but all identifiers are uppercase by default. What error are you getting in mssql for `"\"KEY\""`?

Comment: its getting invalid identifier on ms sql. database varies by customers thats why i need one escape command for all of them.

Comment: Using one escape character instead of another shouldn't make any difference, because Hibernate ORM will then convert it to the right escape char. What's the exact error you are having? Is it at startup, when you query or during an operation?

Comment: its happening while trying to execute related query, and error is ORA-00904: "PERMISSION0_"."key": invalid identifier.for oracle if i use backstick. As i said its working for mssql and postgresql.